# Getting error ImportMismatchError while running py.test

Tags: python, docker, pytest

When I am running tests locally its working fine, but after creating the docker and running inside the container I am getting below error.

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:325: in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
E   KeyError: local('/apis/db/tests')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:356: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
E   KeyError: local('/apis/db/tests/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:362: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:680: in pyimport
    raise self.ImportMismatchError(modname, modfile, self)

_pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: ImportMismatchError('conftest', '/projects/my_project/db/tests/conftest.py', local('/apis/db/tests/conftest.py'))
```

/apis - its the WORKDIR in Dockerfile.

Comment: You probably have some problems with python import paths or with symlinks or whatever. What is `/projects/my_project` and what is `/apis`? Are they directories or symlinks? How are they related to each other?

Comment: @MarSoft /projects is in home directory, and /apis is in docker's home directory, btw I have solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 151):

I have fixed it by removing all *__pycache__* pkg under test/ directory, the issue was when I was creating docker image its picking all my *__pycache__* and **.pyc* files too, at the time when test are running its using my local machine path instead of the path in docker container.

Conclusion: Clear your **.pyc* and *__pycache__* files before creating a docker image.

Comment: You can put these entries in your `.dockerignore` file so that they are ignored during the build phase. Though they would still be picked up if you bind mount your source folders inside the container, in order to run tests while including local modifications.

Comment: To remove this issue, I had to locate `__pycache__` inside directory of the file, which was reporting this error. Thanks.

Comment: Unix command: `find . \( -name '__pycache__' -or -name '*.pyc' \) -delete`

Comment: For my use-case I also had to add the `build` folder to the `.dockerignore`

Answer (score 39):

You can use the [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file to exclude all `__pycache__` folders from being sent to the docker image context:

`.dockerignore` file, excludes `__pycache__` folders and `*.pyc` files from all sub/folders:

```
**/__pycache__
**/*.pyc
```

Comment: Also any virtualenv in `/.venv` or similar.

Answer (score 28):

I am using Python 3.6. In my case, I was getting `ImportMismatchError` in modules with the same name under different packages, e.g., `A/B/main.py` and `C/D/main.py`. Python 3 does not require `__init__.py` file in source folders, but adding `__init__.py` under `A/B` and `C/D` solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and your answer solved it for me as well.
I wonder why did adding `__init__.py` fix it though? I am trying to understand...

Comment: @Newskooler adding an `__init__` file lets python know about the absolute path towards every file in the tree. Without those, if you have 2 different files named the same way under different folders, it will not know which one you're referring to.

Comment: Okay, so essentially even though "Python 3 does not require __init__.py" it kind of does require it if you want it to run properly?

Comment: I had an `ImportPathMismatchError` with python 3.8 and this solved the problem.

Comment: I had an `ImportPathMismatchError` with python 3.7 and this solved the problem.

Comment: I also needed to add `__init__.py` in `A/__init__.py` and `C/__init__.py`.

Comment: Like Alex, I had to add an `__init__.py` at each level of the tree, and it solved my problem.  Deleting the `__pycache__` directories did not solve my problem.  Python 3.10.12

Answer (score 20):

You can set environment variable `PY_IGNORE_IMPORTMISMATCH=1` to skip this errros. It should be fine in simple cases like running tests inside and outside docker container.

Comment: I had a similar problem when running pytest via tox via GitHub actions. This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Seems like you'll make your life a hell with this trying to figure out why something isn't working and then realizing it's using a module with same name from a different path.

Comment: You're right, and that's why I'm talking about "simple cases" =)

Answer (score 17):

Delete all the .pyc files. You can do this by 
`find . -name \*.pyc -delete`

Comment: This is essentially a re-write of @AJ's answer. How dies this add value to the OP question?

Comment: @Tedinoz It's a no-brainer you can copy-paste to fix the problem. Like it or not, many people are just happy with a solution and don't want to understand the background.

Answer (score 3):

Found `__pycache__` files in coverage/fullcoverage/ which are hidden in `jupyter notebook` etc.

simply navigate to the folder and use `rm -r __pyache__/` . This will take care of your pytest.

Comment: Or, delete `__pycache__` directories recursively: `find . -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} \;` Be careful, `rm -rf` is dangerous!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **py.test FILE** from directory **ROOT**, ensure that **FILE** is somewhere under **ROOT**. If it's **ELSEWHERE**, pytest may try to load plugins from **ELSEWHERE** and report ImportMismatchError. That was the cause in my case. Copying **FILE** to under **ROOT** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting `PYTHONPATH` manually to the root of my repo. Inside of this I have a `worktrees/` folder, which contains worktrees, each of which contain a python package. Since I told python to look for packages at the root of my repo, it would consider all packages under `worktrees/` as well, thus leading to the import error. I resolved by flattening this nested structure.

Comment: please explain better