# ImportMismatchError while running tox

Tags: python, virtualenv, importerror, tox

When running my tests with tox in a virtualenv I run into  `py._path.local.LocalPath.ImportMismatchError: ('tfields.__main__', '/builds/dboe/tfields/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tfields/__main__.py', local('/builds/dboe/tfields/tfields/__main__.py'))`.
I keep coming back to [Getting error ImportMismatchError while running py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067609/getting-error-importmismatcherror-while-running-py-test) but removing **pycache** and *.pyc does not solve my issue. See https://gitlab.mpcdf.mpg.de/dboe/tfields/-/jobs/1122409 for the failing example of my ci (You can see in lines 96 and 97 that I remove **pycache** and *.pyc as suggested in the answers to the referred question above).
Any hints or sollutions are very welcome.

Comment: Please share your tox.ini

Comment: @J.G. I don't have a tox.ini but use the setup.cfg. The tox config there is

[tox:tox]
minversion = 3.7
skip_missing_interpreters = true
envlist = py{38}
recreate = true

Comment: Oh wow, I learned something new! Thanks! Anyway, you need to have a `testenv` section, right? Or how do you run the tests? Please update your question above with all the relevant tox configuration (it is easier to read when it is properly formatted)

Comment: Nevermind, I found your repo, cloned it, made the tests run - except one is failing. Preparing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `testenv` section, you have to set either

```
setenv = PY_IGNORE_IMPORTMISMATCH=1
```

or

```
usedevelop = true
```

You can read more about the problem on the pytest bugtracker, see here https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2042

While I have not spend a lot of time on this, I am pretty sure it has to do with the naming of your packages.

The main source folder is called `tfields` and your package is called `tfields`. The problem is that now both the installed package and the folder is available for Python under the same namespace.

When I remember correctly, I had the very same problem for my https://github.com/jugmac00/hibpcli project - and the problem went away, once I put my sourcecode in a `src` directory, and not longer call the top level folder the same as the package name.

If you want to dig deeper, I highly recommend the article by Hynek Schlawack on why to use a `src` layout:

https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/

Answer (score 0):

> When running my tests with tox in a virtualenv

You don't really need to run tox in a virtualenvironment. `Tox` creates a virtualenv to install your project into. Automation tools typically supply standardised tools for a fresh python executable.

Sometimes after refactoring a project; changing the project folder structure for example, causes this. The best remedy usually is simply calling:

```
tox --recreate
```

I *always* do this in my CI/CD. Otherwise it is possible that that caches are used, this can cause trouble for the idempotency of those builds.

If this doesn't work, check whether your build agent cleans up the build directory properly. It might leave remnants from other builds.

This would achieve the same as deleting the `.tox` folder, which you could also consider.

**EDIT**:
I've cloned your project, it has nothing to do with either `pytest` or `tox` im afraid. The structure of your project (imports) is rather broken.

If you apply the following rules you should be improving:

- Use only absolute imports (and stick with it < PEP8 advice)
- Don't add imports in the **init** if you do not need them
- Make imports as specific as possible (explicit better than implicit < zen of python)

Finally, there is an import loop happening somewhere (e.g. file1 import file2, file2 import file1). But i'll let you find that one.

Comment: Thanks @Shine! Unfortunately that did not do the trick: https://gitlab.mpcdf.mpg.de/dboe/tfields/-/jobs/1126524

Comment: Thanks again, @Shine. I am rather astonished that you have an import loop. Locally all my tests run and an import tfields works well. I would appreciate a stacktrace. With regards to the absolute imports: Have a look at the last comment of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811463/when-to-use-absolute-imports - However I changed all imports to absolute and the problem remains: https://gitlab.mpcdf.mpg.de/dboe/tfields/-/jobs/1135480
With regards to imports "you do not need": The point of imports in __init__.py is to expose the namespace of the module, so you do not need them by definition.